# Redirecting to another page(route) from a React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need some help to solve the following issue with using `React`.

In some web app I have a landing page, where I want to redirect the user to the login page in case she or he is not logged in.

I want to use the following landing page (taken from some tutorial I found on the net) in order to use it as a model for mine.

The problem is that this is a *function component* while my landing page is a *class component*. According to what I understand I guess I need to consider the code inside *useEffect* and (somewhat) transfer it to *componentDidMount()* in my *class component*. But I don't know how to do that. *history.replace* will not work in a *class component* (no Hooks in Classes). Any advice from a more `React` experienced  user will be very welcome.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import { auth, db, logout } from "./firebase";

....

function Dashboard() {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  ....

  useEffect(() => { // Important part for my question !
    if (loading) return;
    if (!user) return history.replace("/");
    ....
  }, [user, loading]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/*...*/}
      <button className="dashboard__btn" onClick={logout}>
        Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Here is what I tried on my Class Component:

```
class MyCompo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("--componentDidMount(MyCompo)--");
    const { history } = this.props
    history.push("/login");
  }
  .....
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: history is undefined
componentDidMount
```

=============== Added information ===============

Below is the relevant part of the code I have been working on:

This part is what works:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={TopMenu}>
    {true && <Redirect to="/login" />}
</Route>
```

What I tried in the Links Component did not work.

The code:

```
....

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={TopMenu}>
        {true && <Redirect to="/login" />}
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/section1" component={Section1Page}/>
      <Route exact path="/section2" component={Section2Page}/>
      <Route exact path="/section3" component={Section3Page}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

....

const TopMenu = () => {
    return (
        <div className='page_container'>
            <Title/>
            <Links path='/'/>
            <button className="dashboard__btn" onClick={logout}>
                Logout
            </button>
        </div>
    )
};


class Links extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }
  
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("--componentDidMount(Links)--");
      // This is some code I tried with no success.
      const { history } = this.props
      //history.push("/login");
    }
  
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      console.log("--componentDidUpdate(Links)--");
    }
  
    render() {
    return (
            <div className='links_container'>
                {(this.props.path != '/mng') &&
                    <React.StrictMode>
                        <Link to='/mng'>{mnMgrStr()}</Link><br/>
                    </React.StrictMode>}
                {(this.props.path != '/other') &&
                    <React.StrictMode>
                        <Link to='/other'>{otherInpStr()}</Link><br/>
                    </React.StrictMode>}
                 .......
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dashboard` appears to be a function component, the `useHistory` hook should work. Or is this what you are trying to copy? If so then please share *your* code/attempt. What version of `react-router`|`react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: Is there a specific reason your component has to be a Class component? In any case, you can use the withRouter HOC, and access `history` from `this.props`

Comment: @Drew_Reeze. Yes indeed Dashboard is a function component (and it works). My problem is that I want to make it work for a class component.

Comment: Can we see a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt then? And verify what version of `react-router` you are working with?

Comment: @Keno. The reason is that my component is already working as a class. I don't really want to transform it to a function component. The end of your comment may be what I want to follow ("use the withRouter HOC, and access history from this.props"). It is just that I don't know how to do that at this point.

Comment: I am using  "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0" (Info from package.json)

Comment: Please update with how any props are passed to this `MyCompo` component and how it is rendered. It should be rendered by a `Route` or have a `Route` higher than it in the ReactTree. Are you rendering a router and routes? Double check the *intalled* version, from the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`.

Comment: No props is passed (at least not explicitly).

Comment: npm list react-router-dom -> react-router-dom@5.3.0

Comment: Has an answer here addressed/resolved your question?

Answer (score 0):

Following the example on the [React Router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) you can use `withRouter` if your component isn't already receiving the route props, otherwise you can access `history` from the props.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    const { history } = this.props
    // do whatever with history here
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion, but I get an error see the addition I just made at the end of my post.

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` version 5 there are a couple ways a class component can access the `history` object.

1. Rendered directly by a `Route` component via the `component`, or `render` or `children` function props so [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (*i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`*) are passed.

   - `component`: `<Route path="....." component={MyCompo} />`
   - `render`: `<Route path="....." render={routeProps => <MyCompo {...routeProps} />} />`

   Access the `history` object from the passed route props:

   ```
   class MyCompo extends React.Component {
     componentDidMount() {
       const { history } = this.props;
       history.push("/login");
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Decorated by the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component so the route props are injected.

   ```
   import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

   class MyCompo extends React.Component {
     componentDidMount() {
       const { history } = this.props;
       history.push("/login");
     }
     ...
   }

   export default withRouter(MyCompo);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I am still getting an error (TypeError: history is undefined). Obviously I need to look into this "withRouter thing", because I had never seen it before and don't know how to use it.

Comment: While looking at the doc to solve my problem I discovered that using <Redirect to="/login" />} may be much simpler to use.

Comment: @Michel Are you rendering `MyCompo` within the subtree of a `Router` component? The `Redirect` may work, but it too may have issues if not rendered within a `Router` component.

Comment: @Drew_Reeze. As far as I can say and with what I have tried, I already know the Redirect works. Concerning the question "Are you rendering MyCompo within the subtree of a Router component? "; my knowledge and understanding of React Router is at this point so limited that I am not even sure of the meaning of the question, but I think the answer is YES.

Comment: @Michel No worries, we all start from *somewhere*. The answer to my question would/could be pretty trivial to find. Can you update your question to include your app/router/routing code, all the way through to where you are trying to render this `MyCompo` class component?

Comment: I added to the post information that should give you what you need. Please have a look when you get a chance.

Comment: @Michel Ok, `Links` isn't rendered by a `Route` so it's not passed the route props, but you can decorate it with the `withRouter` HOC, i.e. `withRouter(Links)`.

Comment: When you write "Links isn't rendered by a Route", is it because it does not appear in the <Router><Switch>...</Switch></Router> block ? Then I need to learn how to use withRouter(Links). But for my immediate need Redirect is simple and works, though I still need to figure out how to replace "true" in my code with a boolean variable indicating if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: @Michel Oh, sorry, I meant that it's not ***directly*** rendered by a `Route`, i.e. it's nothing like `<Route component={Links} />`.

Comment: Well, there is nothing to be sorry about, it seems you're saying  the same as I understood. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope by answering this question I can save lot of time of others. Don't need to panic it's not a major issue. I will explain step by step reason and solution.
First of all why this happening is

1. In react-router-dom **V6 (version 6) latest ** there is no history export or redirect.
2. There is navigate construct.
   So to achieve in functional component there is useNavigate() hook.
   Now coming to answer...
   To redirect in class component using react-router-dom V6 we have to use  component.

So now one has to follow the following steps:

1. Import navigate

   import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
2. Use Navigate to redirect

So above I discussed syntax to do so now coming to your exact problem
You have to redirect user to login if he is not logged in
You can follow these steps:

1. create state to store status of user like logged in or not (inside constructor of class)

   this.state = {
   userLogged: false,
   };
2. in your render method you have to add some condition like if user is not logged in take user to login page. see below..

```js
 render() {
    const { userLogged } = this.state;

    if (goToPay) {
      return (
        <Navigate to="/cart" state={selectedTiffin} props={selectedTiffin} />
      );
    }
}
```

That's it.
It can be confusing so I am giving full example so you can save your lot of time..

```js
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

class Solve extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userLogged: false,
    };
  }
  // here you can write code to set the status of user like logged in or not
  render() {
    const { userLogged } = this.state;

    if (userLogged ) {
      return (
        <Navigate to="/cart" />
      );
    }

    return (
      <>
        Here you can return your original component that should be render when user is log in
 </>
);
  }
}
```

I hope this will help and work. Thank You